# Error: Ambiguous reference to member 'open' (Mac OSx) Swift 3

Tags: macos, file, swift3, nsworkspace

My goal is to open a specified file using the default app associated with its type.

I have the correct path. I do not know how to open a file (e.g. photo.png)

[image: I'm trying to open file by using URL.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error occurs because you have to use the **shared** workspace (`open` is not a class method):

```
NSWorkspace.shared().open(...
```

However if you want to *open a specified file using the default app associated with its type* you are using the wrong API. You are looking for

```
NSWorkspace.shared().openFile(..
```

This API expects a `String` rather than an `URL`.

Comment: Great explanation! Thanks for providing a well-detailed answer.